# (Java) Generating random number for division program

Tags: java, math

Hi I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a division program that can generate 2 random numbers and the condition is that the first number must be more than the second and they give no remainder. If the number generated does not meet the condition it keeps generating until the conditions are met. Can anyone help me fix my error?

```
randomnum1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);
randomnum2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);

while (randomnum1 < randomnum2 && randomnum1/randomnum2 % 2 != 0) {
            randomnum1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);
            randomnum2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);
            int number1 = randomnum1;
            int number2 = randomnum2;

        int a = number1/number2;
    
    //rest of program is below this
```

Comment: An easier way to do this is to pick two factors, x and y, and multiply them to get z = x*y.  Then ask what the quotient of the product, z, and one of the factors, say x, is.  The correct answer is the other factor you picked, which would be y.  You can completely eliminate the loop in this case and get three numbers which satisfy the condition you're looking for in exactly one pass.

Comment: Just to mention for your future endeavour in this field. As a piece of advice, the way you want to implement this by using indefinite loop, is not efficient by all means. In real life scenarios, such implementation would never be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` condition checks that the division result is even `randomnum1/randomnum2 % 2 != 0`
You should replace :

```java
while (randomnum1 < randomnum2 && randomnum1/randomnum2 % 2 != 0) {
```

With

```java
while (randomnum1 < randomnum2 || randomnum1 % randomnum2 != 0) {
// while (!(randomnum1 >= randomnum2 && randomnum1 % randomnum2 == 0)) {
    randomnum1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);
    randomnum2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);
}
// randomnum1 and randomnum2 now match your expectations
int a = number1/number2;
```

As `rand1 modulo rand2 == 0` means that

> they give no remainder

Comment: Hi I got an error with this because it says randomnums must be initialized. How do I post more of the code here? Im new to stackoverflow

Comment: @JohnDoe619 you should assign them before the `while` loop just like you did in your post. Initialize them with `randomnum1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);
randomnum2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*9);` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       int randomnum1=1 + (int)(Math.random()*99);
       int randomnum2=1 + (int)(Math.random()*99);
       

       while(randomnum1 % randomnum2 != 0 || randomnum1==randomnum2) {
           //prints first numbers generated 
           System.out.println(randomnum1+" "+randomnum2);
           randomnum1=1 + (int)(Math.random()*99);
           randomnum2=1 + (int)(Math.random()*99);
           
           }
       if (true) {
               //prints  numbers generated that made the statement true
           System.out.print("true :"+randomnum1+" "+randomnum2);
           }
       }
       
       
       }
```

Comment: `randomnum1 != randomnum2` is unnecessary, because `randomnum1<randomnum2`...

Comment: And you need to replace `&&` with `||`, and to check also if the 2 numbers are equals - if so, you need to generate them again...

Comment: @Avi yeah the first answer is right , but you are wrong about the || , read the question again , the numbers remainder must be = 0.

Comment: If the remainder is not 0 **or** the first number is not bigger than the other, we need to generate them again

Comment: If just the remainder is not 0 - we also should generate the numbers again

Comment: and randomnum1<randomnum2   is unnecessary too

Comment: Wow! The code is significantly cleaner without  `randomnum1<randomnum`!!! That's really nice!!!

Comment: On second thought, if the numbers are equal it will not generate them again...

Comment: yeah , ```|| randomnum1==randomnum2``` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it can be by using an infinite loop and breaking the loop when the conditions are met.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomNum1, randomNum2;
        while (true) {// An infinite loop

            randomNum1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            randomNum2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);

            if (randomNum1 > randomNum2 && randomNum1 % randomNum2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(randomNum1 + " / " + randomNum2 + " = " + (randomNum1 / randomNum2));
                break;// Break the loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
8 / 2 = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way, without having to use any loop, is to do some mathematical tricks as follows:

```
public class SpecialRandom{
    
    public void generate(){
        int first = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
        int second = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
        // to guarantee the second is always smaller
        if (second>=first){ second%=first; }
        if (second==0) { second++; }
        first += second - (first%second); //to  correct remainder
        System.out.println((first>second && first%second==0)
                            + " : " +first+ " ,  " +second);
    }
    
     /*TESTING*/
     public static void main(String []args){
       SpecialRandom sr = new SpecialRandom();
       for(int j=0; j<25; j++){ sr.generate(); }
     } 
}
```

### Result

```
true : 28 ,  4
true : 64 ,  32
true : 22 ,  11
true : 18 ,  3
true : 28 ,  14
true : 18 ,  6
true : 92 ,  23
true : 96 ,  6
true : 130 ,  65
true : 28 ,  14
true : 87 ,  29
true : 87 ,  29
true : 74 ,  37
true : 112 ,  56
true : 66 ,  6
true : 10 ,  1
true : 88 ,  44
true : 68 ,  34
true : 156 ,  78
true : 22 ,  11
true : 95 ,  1
true : 86 ,  43
true : 14 ,  1
true : 82 ,  41
true : 98 ,  14
```